# Substring specific text using javascript

Tags: javascript, substring

```
<li class="item">hello?james</a></li>
<li class="item">goodbye?michael</a></li>
```

I want to extract the text that is after the sign "?" -> james, michael

I tried using a substring method but it only works if I specify the starting and the ending like substr(5,10) or substr(5) etc.

I'm using this when I extract from another file in a foreach php method, so I need everything that is after "?".

Is there any method in which I can substring starting with a character (eg. "?") or a specific string ?

Many thanks!

Comment: `"hello?james".split("?")[1];`

Comment: Or str.substr(str.indexOf('?')+1)

Comment: Thank you. Matthew example worked fine form me.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a regex with capture groups**

Regular expressions will make it easy to match your HTML and using capture groups (parenthesis) you can extract the names from the string:

```
var myString = YOUR_HTML_HERE;
var myRegexp = /<li .*\?([a-zA-Z0-1]*)</g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);  // james.
```

**Execute the regex multiple times to get all matches**

You can run the regex again in the original string to get the next match. To get all of them, do this:

```
while (match != null) {
    match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
    alert(match[1]); // michael
}
```